Relative homology is homotopy invariant in both arguments?
I'd like Definition 2.6 below to hold (if I'm properly interpreting it), as I want to use it as a lemma for solving a larger scale problem of mine.
I'm using Hatcher's Algebraic Topology as a reference, as well as this nLab page.
nLab gives this definition:

Definition 2.6. Relative homology is homotopy invariant in both arguments.

nLab offers no proof of the statement. Also I want to make sure that I'm precisely understanding what this means. Let infix $\underset H \leftrightarrow $ denote homotopy equivalence and $\underset I \leftrightarrow$ denote an isomorphism.
(a)
Does this mean that for good pairs of spaces $(X, A)$ and $(X' , A')$ the following proposition holds?
$$(X \underset H \leftrightarrow X') \land (A \underset H \leftrightarrow A') \implies H_n(X, A) \underset I \leftrightarrow H_n(X', A') $$
(b)
Can I see a demonstration for why this is, if true? I searched through Hatcher but couldn't find this theorem. I wouldn't be surprised if it comes out as some consequence of the excision theorem, but I can't see a straightforward way of proving this.

nLab is a bit short, but Hatcher contains all you need.

Relative homology groups $H_n(X,A)$ are introduced in Section 2.1 (p.115 ff).

On p.118 Hatcher shows that a map of pairs $f : (X,A) \to (Y,B)$ induces a homomorphism $f_* : H_n(X,A) \to H_n(Y,B)$.
Proposition 2.19 says that if two maps $f ,g : (X,A) \to (Y, B)$ are homotopic as maps of pairs, then $f_∗ = g_∗$.


The statement "relative homology is homotopy invariant in both arguments" means this:

Given a homotopy equivalence of pairs $f : (X,A) \to (Y,B)$  (which means that there exists $g : (Y,B) \to (X,A)$ such that $g \circ f \simeq id_{(X,A)}$ and $f \circ g \simeq id_{(Y,B)}$ where $\simeq$ denotes "homotopic as maps of pairs"), then $f_*$ is an isomorphism.

This fact follows immediately from Proposition 2.19. However, it is not a definition ("Definition 2.6" in nLab), but a theorem. We can at best say that our above explanation defines what "relative homology is homotopy invariant in both arguments" means. If so, nLab has to be blamed for calling something a definition, but omitting the defining property.

One can also formulate this concept by saying that relative homology is a functor on the homotopy category of topological pairs. Hatcher glides over this, but I've always found this point to be clarifying.
